# Incorrect Date() outcome

Tags: javascript, date

I'm using the javascript `Date()` function to work with dates.

I have the following:

```
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    console.log(y);
    console.log(m);
    console.log(d);
```

This returns, in the console:

```
2013
9
1
```

Which correct me  If I'm wrong, is 1 month behind the actual date of today.

I'm in the UK, so could BST be affecting the outcome of this?

Thanks

Comment: The 9 means october and 0 means Janauary. The default range for months is an array so from 0 to 11.

Comment: yes it's correct only. Because month start from 0. that means Jan = 0 and Dec = 11 .

Comment: Ah, that was incredibly stupid of myself for not realising!

Comment: @user1970557  happens to every programmer someday :P

Comment: More on [*Javascript Date() function*](http://javascript.info/tutorial/datetime-functions)

Comment: Not sure why this question has 2 upvotes, simple matter of not reading the docs.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I think this question meets the fact, that is worth to be a part of the archive. SO shall be also an archive for programming knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var m = date.getMonth();
```

Because month begins at `0`.

```
0-January
1-February
2-March
3-April
4-May
5-June
6-July
7-August
8-September
9-October
10-November
11-December
```

Answer (score 1):

[JavaScript months are `0` based.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

> **Date.getMonth**
>   Returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a
>   zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year).

Just to be confusing!

So always remember to add 1 to the result of `date.getMonth()` if you want the actual month number.

Answer (score 1):

The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.

Source: w3schools

So, you are getting 1 month less than the actual month of your local time.

You can use:

```
console.log(("0" + (m+1)).slice(-2))
```

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScript` month start from 0.